# Where can I download an old VSTS Agent from?

Tags: svn, azure-devops, agent

I am trying to create a private VSTS agent to build from an SVN repository, however when I trigger a build it gives me the following error:

> No agent found in pool xxx which satisfies the specified
>   demands: svn, Cmd, Agent.Version -gtVersion 1.83.0

- svn I understand and I will download that client.
- Cmd I don't understand, because this works if I select a Git build on the same Agent.
- Agent.Version I guess is needed at 1.83.0 because we are using SVN? Because this is also not an issue when we attempt the same with Git.

If it is forcing me to use 1.83.0, where is that version? I cannot see any download sites with these older versions? I think the oldest I have seen is like 2.1 or something.

Comment: It's looking for a version _greater_ than 1.83, which it sounds like yours is.  I believe the error is just listing all demands, rather than the ones that aren't fulfilled.  Try installing SVN and I'll bet it'll work.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, once you understand that the error is what looks like an exact error, but is more generic than that!
Thanks Patrick.

Comment: Quick update, it was indeed just the SVN install that was causing the issue. The other messages were a red herring.

In the latest version of Tortoise SVN it does not automatically install the SVN.exe, so I just had to repair the install and then it worked fine.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshootingthe issue, you can check below aspects:

1. **Update your private agent to latest**

   You can check the current agent version with below steps:

   In the Agent Pools page (https://account.visualstudio.com/_admin/_AgentPool) -> click the agent pool -> click your private agent -> Capabilities Tab -> check the value for Agent.Version (the latest agent version for now is 2.133.3).

   [image]

   To update the agent, you can click the `...` button on the agent pool, and then click Update All Agents.

   [image]
2. **Make sure svn and cmd can be execute on your agent machine**

   To check cmd, you can open cmd in the run window to check if it can be opened.

   To check svn, make sure it installs on the machine. And if build agent still can be find svn, you can add svn.exe into environment variables or add capability for the svn.

   [image]

**BTW:** to download old agent version, you can get from [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/releases).